# Форматирование строк php в js

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Есть строка на php вытаскиваю её из БД, там храниться html. Ок, на php всё норм но мне надо её передать в js. Форматирую строку через битрикс функцию HTMLToTxt(), все рано остаются ненужные спец символы и всякая дичь от пробелов &nbsr; и всякое такое, писать регулярку не могу потому что текста много и неизвестно что там ещё попадется, отсюда вопрос может есть какие то функции в php или битрикс, что бы отформатировать и js не ругался?

[image: Строка на php]

Вставляю в js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдаёт ошибку!

[image: Вот такая ошибка]

JS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ERORR
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что бы вам помогли, покажите, какую ошибку выдает JS, какой код при этом выполняется, что передается(как строка), какого результата вы хотите достичь

Comment: Ругается на синтаксис амперсанты, и спец символы как бы почистить на php что бы нечего не оcталось, от HTML? Вообще) Но сохранить смысл!

Comment: А что далее вы со строкой делаете? Для строки все равно, что там лежит

Comment: @SwaD судя по скриншоту, ТС пытается вручную строить json, вместо `json_encode`, и получает ошибку некорректных (неэкранированных) символов в json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите получить чистый текст, то можно попробовать двойное преобразование:

```
strip_tags(html_entity_decode($arUser['UF_EXPERT_DESCRIPTION']));
```

[html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php) — Преобразует HTML-сущности в соответствующие им символы

[strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php) — Удаляет теги HTML и PHP из строки

Если же вам нужно просто построить корректный json, то используйте [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php):

```
$json = json_encode([
    [
        'text' => HTMLToTxt($arUser['UF_EXPERT_DESCRIPTION']),
        'fontSize' => 10,
        'margin' => [0, 5, 0, 0],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Нет это кусок библиотеки make pdf rкоторой нужна корректная строка. И такая шляпа strip_tags(html_entity_decode($arUser['UF_EXPERT_DESCRIPTION'])); не работает, ок всё почистилось, но всё рано синтаксическая ошибка. Я не могу присвоить это даже в переменную js :( Добавил скрин ошибки сверху

Comment: попробуйте как тут https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/71716/blog/8992/ использовать битриксовскую функцию PhpToJSObject

Comment: Вообще круть! Я замучился с этой шляпой, большое спасибо всё работет, очень классно:) СПАСИБО